# How to determine what dll's are causing trouble in Azure deployment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, deployment

After that infamous Microsoft MVC Security Update MS14-059 a couple of days ago, my solution wouldn't build. I applied the solutions suggested on this site. For every project in my solution that referenced System.Web.Mvc I...

- added a new system.web.mvc 4.0.0.1 reference
- set CopyLocal to true
- updated web/app.config bindingredirect: oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.1"

Locally, everything runs fine again. But when i publish to Azure (cloud Service) the deployment stays in a busy-ready-cycling loop ('Instance 0 of role ... is cycling'), even after multiple tries. Apperenly this hints to certain dll's that Azure cannot find. I can remote desktop to an instance of the cloud service, but that hasnt made me any wiser (not sure what to look for either)

How can i determine what dll's (in what project) are giving me trouble, and what would a solution be?

Comment: "*Apparently this hints to certain dll's that Azure cannot find*" - actually, it hints to the role not being able to start up which can be due to *countless* reasons. I suggest you log into the VM and take a look at the log files rather than assuming what the problem is, I imagine it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Look into Event Logs when your RDP into the instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of troubleshooting walkthroughs at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx that will help you diagnose pretty much any type of role recycling or startup errors.  My guess is that you are facing scenario 7 which is a dependency failure in WaIISHost.exe, and most likely because you are using app.config instead of your {DLLName}.DLL.Config (ie. WebRole1.DLL.Config).